# Effective sample size in Bayesian t test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian

In a paper by **[Rouder et al (2009, p. 234)](http://pcl.missouri.edu/sites/default/files/Rouder.bf_.pdf)**, authors indicate that their formula for obtaining a default Bayes Factor from **[their equation (1) on page 231](http://pcl.missouri.edu/sites/default/files/Rouder.bf_.pdf)** can be used for any type of t-test.

But they mention that for the **two independent samples t-test** case, ***N*** (total sample size) for two samples (N1, N2) may be computed as ***"effective sample size"***:

***N = (N1 x N2) / (N1 + N2)***

**Questions:**

**1-** Conceptually, what is effective sample size (does it have a fixed formula)?

**2-** Is this way of computing "**effective sample size**" in any way related to **resolving imbalance in the design** (i.e., base rate differences; e.g., one group has 17 subjects, the other group has 12 subjects)?

Comment: I have been looking at the paper page 231.  Although they have some credible references I feel more comfortable with the paper by Kass and Raftery in the Journal of the American Statistical Association Volume 90 Number 140.  This is a review article on Bayes Factors.  The best I can make of this is that these test are looking at the odds favoring one hypothesis test over another in a Bayesian context.  I am Puzzled by effective sample size and the formula given in your question.

Comment: Michael, thanks for your comment. I agree that Kass & Raftery (1995) is an elegant paper. My issue here is the Rouder et al's (2009) basis for use and definition of "effective sample size" for two-samples t-test? My conceptual understanding regarding **"effective sample size"** is from [**HERE**](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/12/effective_sample_size.html). But I'm wondering how effective sample size used by Rouder et al (2009) as I indicated in my questions above?

Comment: I would like to be helpful.  I looked at "HERE" but I don't have time to look at all that discussion.  My feeling was that when comparing two estimators (maybe one is efficient) and each estimator has a variance.  Then the effect sample size would be the number required to make both variances equal.